# How to iterate large query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I know how to make pagination but it doesn't fit my requirements because underlying query of pagination is updating itself whenever i need next paged result. So i am looking simple solution to iterate one by one whole results of query efficiently. Please take a look below example.

```
var urls = db.Websites.Select(s => s.Website)
             .Except(db.OldWebsites.Select(s => s.Website));

foreach (var url in urls)
{
   //process items
}
```

I just want to know that the solution is really efficiently does iteration whole results or not. I am not exactly sure that the solution is loading rows one by one without loading all results to memory.

Can someone verify this or suggest better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Entity Framework streaming results instead of buffering as default. Calling AsStreaming method as below gives warning as : "Queries are now streaming by default unless a retrying ExecutionStrategy is used.

```
foreach (var item in db.Websites.AsStreaming()) { }
```

Just needs to be carefull that DbContext doesn't hold references for iterated results. Anonymous types or primitive results already not tracked so it needs to call AsNoTracking for Entity results like

```
db.Websites.AsNoTracking()
```